# Julia stdin error with Vim and AsyncRun in WIndows

Tags: windows, vim, julia

I am using Vim in Windows with the plugin AsyncRun; when I try to execute a simple `julia <filename>` I get the following:

> `ERROR: error initializing stdin in uv_dup: Unknown system error 6 (Unknown system error 6 6)`.

This should be a julia-Windows issue since the same procedure in linux works correctly. Python and other languages also function with Vim & Asyncrun in Windows.  Calling `julia <filename>` in either cmd or PowerShell executes as expected.

Is there a cli option or configuration for julia that can fix this?

EDIT: This bug has been fixed.